# Tikz node style that will programmatically modify the node content

Tags: tikz-pgf

I’d like to set up a tikz style, say `/uml/interface`, that would modify the node content following some macro of my choosing. For example, it would prefix the node text with some text of my choosing. I would use it as follows.

```
\path node[/uml/interface] (MyInterface) {MyInterface};
```

And as a result of applying the `/uml/interface` style the node content would become `<<interface>> \\ MyInterface`.

I have used the font change command, as follows.

```
\tikzset{/uml/interface/.style={rectangle, draw, every text node/.style={font=\bfseries}}}
```

But I did not find in the PGF manual how to programmatically modify the node text itself.

Ideally, I would do something like this:

```
\tikzset{/uml/interface/.style={…, every text node/.style={applyMacro=\umlinterface}}}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\umlinterface}[1]{<<interface>> \\ \textbf{#1}}
```

. As a workaround I could typeset my node as follows:

```
\path node[/uml/interface] (MyInterface) {\umlinterface{MyInterface}};
```

, but I’d prefer having a clean node content part (for consistence, maintenance, readability, and avoiding refactoring all my related node commands when I decide to add a prefix).

Comment: TikZ v3 has a key `node content`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can apply a macro to the node text by injecting it with `execute at begin node`.  This works, because in the TikZ code this key is immediately followed by `\bgroup`.

```
/uml/interface/.style={
  rectangle, draw,
  execute at begin node=\umlinterface
}
```

To be safe, I added another level of grouping.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % just for the guillemets
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\umlinterface}[1]{<<interface>> \\ \textbf{#1}}
\tikzset{
  /uml/interface/.style={
    rectangle, draw,
    execute at begin node=\umlinterface\bgroup,
    execute at end node=\egroup
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[/uml/interface] (MyInterface) {MyInterface};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Nice! (+1) Just add `align=left` to the style to allow the linebreak to work properly.

Comment: @PaulGessler Unfortunately, my solution breaks `align=left`.  I don't know why, yet.  I have to explicitely put `text width=…`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks, this looks like a good solution for me… If we manage to solve the `align` problem!

Comment: Also the suggested strategy has odd behavior inside a beamer frame. It works with `execute at begin node=\textbf` but not with `execute at begin node=\myowncommand`, not sure why. I guess it is related to align-not-working anyway so I’ll wait to see if anybody better acquainted to (la)tex than me can work it out…

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290559/why-can-t-i-use-execute-at-begin-node-together-with-align) is a patch to render `execute at begin node` compatible with `align=`. Unfortunately it involves fiddling with the inner workings of tikz. I would not go that far just to get my "prefix" functionality. I’d like to find a simpler solution, but I guess none exist currently.

Answer (score 8):

Slightly different from your expected input, but here's one approach using the `node contents` key mentioned by percusse.

I use the interface name as an argument to the style, and piece together the full `node contents` inside the definition of the style.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % just for the guillemets
\tikzset{/uml/interface/.style={
  % ... more style defs as needed ...
  rectangle, draw, align=left,
  node contents={<<interface>> \\ \textbf{#1}},
}}

\begin{document}
\tikz{\node[/uml/interface=MyInterface];}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clever use of node contents! I’d favor Henri’s solution if we can make it work, but it is good to have a backup solution.

Comment: For other readers: Note that if you use `node contents`, then you **must** specify your node as `\node[styles];`, and cannot use `\node[styles] (label);` or `\node[styles] (label) {contents};`.

Comment: @FWDekker yes, this is because using `node contents` causes the parsing of the node to stop after the close of the options block. If you want to add a node name you can use the alternate syntax using options for that: `\node[/uml/interface=MyInterface,name=label];`. If you want to inherit the style but override the node contents, you can add another `node contents` option after the style: `\node[/uml/interface,name=anotherlabel,node contents={Overridden contents}];`.