# Why can’t I use “execute at begin node” together with “align”?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to design a tikz style that will modify a node content according to some function of mine. As suggested in an answer to the [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286314/tikz-node-style-that-will-programmatically-modify-the-node-content), I can use the “execute at begin node” key for this. But it does not play well with “align” and linebreaks. Any idea why? (I suspect something related to the way `\\` works, but I am not sure; replacing with `\newline` shows no improvement.)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% First picture: the align instruction works.
% The prefix word appears, as expected, on top of MyTest.
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[align=left] {prefix \\ MyTest};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\myfunction}[1]{prefix \\ #1}
% Second picture: now align has no apparent effect any more.
% The prefix word and MyTest appear together on the same line.
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[align=left, execute at begin node=\myfunction] {MyTest};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: align installs a minipage you are overwriting it and making it an `hbox`

Comment: @percusse Good point. I now see that this is probably explained in the pgf manual (although I don’t really understand it when it speaks about the `node halign header` part). I can’t find a workaround however in the manual. E.g., using a tabular inside `\myfunction` definition yields “Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.”.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `node contents` ?

Comment: For consistency reasons, I’d prefer keeping the usual syntax for nodes if possible, where the “contents” go in the brackets following the nodes. This way I can change the style and not change the rest of the syntax. Here, I consider the added prefix as an element of style, which I agree is only one of the possible points of view. But you are right, `node contents` is certainly a viable option in absence of a solution for `align`.

Comment: @percusse `minipage` is still there, try `\node[align=left, execute at begin node=\myfunction] {MyTest\\second line};`.

Comment: @Symbol1 It's a box in a minipage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `tikz.code.tex` line 3713, there is the definition of `\tikz@do@fig`. This is the essential part of typesetting nodes. In the definition one can see `\tikz@atbegin@node` at line 3736 and `\tikz@halign@check` at 3755.

As one might guess, `\tikz@atbegin@node` is the macro the stores `execute at begin node`-codes, and `\tikz@halign@check` checks if you says `align=something` and build up a `\halign`. Therefore by default your prefix is not involved in `\halign`-construction and hence is put aside the node content. Try

```
\node[align=left,execute at begin node=\myfunction]{MyTest\\aa\\bb\\cc};
```

to see this clearer.

To solve this, a stupid method is to rearrange the code so that `\tikz@halign@check` happens before `\tikz@atbegin@node`. A stupid instance is

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myfunction}[1]{prefix \\ #1}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@do@fig{%  
    % Ok, reset all node part boxes
    \pgfutil@for\tikz@temp:=\tikz@nodepart@list\do{%
      \expandafter\setbox\csname pgfnodepart\tikz@temp box\endcsname=\box\pgfutil@voidb@x%
    }%
    \setbox\pgfnodeparttextbox=\hbox%
      \bgroup%
        \tikzset{every text node part/.try}%
        \ifx\tikz@textopacity\pgfutil@empty%
        \else%
          \pgfsetfillopacity{\tikz@textopacity}%
          \pgfsetstrokeopacity{\tikz@textopacity}%
        \fi%
        \pgfinterruptpicture%
          \ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty%
            \tikz@textfont%  
          \else%
            \begingroup%
                \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@text@width}%
              \pgfutil@minipage[t]{\pgf@x}\leavevmode\hbox{}%
                \tikz@textfont%  
                \tikz@text@action%
          \fi%
          \bgroup%
            \aftergroup\unskip%
            \ifx\tikz@textcolor\pgfutil@empty%
            \else%
              \pgfutil@colorlet{.}{\tikz@textcolor}%
            \fi%
            \pgfsetcolor{.}%
            \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\pgfutil@voidb@x%
            \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\pgfutil@voidb@x%
            \tikz@uninstallcommands%
            \iftikz@handle@active@code%  
              \tikz@orig@shorthands%
              \let\tikz@orig@shorthands\pgfutil@empty%
            \fi%
            \ifnum\the\catcode`\;=\active\relax\expandafter\let\tikz@activesemicolon=\tikz@origsemi\fi%
            \ifnum\the\catcode`\:=\active\relax\expandafter\let\tikz@activecolon=\tikz@origcolon\fi%
            \ifnum\the\catcode`\|=\active\relax\expandafter\let\tikz@activebar=\tikz@origbar\fi%
            \aftergroup\tikz@fig@collectresetcolor%
            \tikz@halign@check%
            \tikz@atbegin@node%
            \ignorespaces%
}

\tikz\node[align=left,execute at begin node=\myfunction]{MyTest\\aa\\bb\\cc};

\end{document}
```